# github.io блокируются ajax запросы

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, github-pages

Все приложения с ajax запросами на github.io выдают ошибку "Смешанного содержимого". К примеру: https://zzharuk.github.io/local_weather_widget/

```
function getWeather(location, value, callback) {
    var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather";
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: url,
        jsonCallback: 'jsonp',
        data: {
            appid:"3556435b983a95646ad9cab4a5ee0943",
            units: value,
            lat:location.latitude,
            lon:location.longitude
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            callback(data);
        }
    });
}
function LocalWeather() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '//freegeoip.net/json/',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (location) {
                getWeather(location,"metric",function (data) {
                    console.log(location);
                    console.log(data);
                 })
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Решил проблему через proxy

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.